# Hold textinput as readonly for 4s on wrong input

Tags: javascript, html, css

For below code,

```
<input type="text" name="textinput" ><br>

<style>
    input:-moz-read-only { /* For Firefox */
       background-color: red;
    }

    input:read-only {
       background-color: red;
    }

    .hang{
       -moz-animation-name: example;
       animation-name: example;
       -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
        animation-duration: 4s;
     }
</style>

<script>
    document.formex.numberinput.onchange = checkIfNumber;
    function checkIfNumber(){
         if (parseInt(document.formex.numberinput.value) == NaN){
            document.formex.numberinput.innerHTML = document.formex.numberinput.value;
            document.formex.numberinput.readOnly = "true";
            document.formex.numberinput.className = "hang";
            document.formex.numberinput.readOnly = "false";
          }
     }
</script>
```

---

callback function is suppose to check, if the input is `number` primitive type.

`if` block of callback function only executes the last assignment.

Can you please help me understand the problem?

Comment: document.formex.numberinput.readOnly = "false"; won´t really wait for animation to end

Comment: watch out for `parseInt` without the second argument. If someone enters "0xAF" it may say that it is a valid number... See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#ECMAScript_5_removes_octal_interpretation) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setTimeout` and update your code to following.

```
 function checkIfNumber(){
         if (isNaN(parseInt(document.formex.numberinput.value))){
            document.formex.numberinput.innerHTML = document.formex.numberinput.value;
            document.formex.numberinput.readOnly = "true";
            document.formex.numberinput.className = "hang";
            setTimeout(function(){            
               document.formex.numberinput.readOnly = false;
            }, 4000);
          }
     }
```

Comment: [here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/acadgild/assignments/session7/assignment3/file.html) I still see that those three lines before timeout do not execute

Comment: @overexchange - Please check my updated answer. To check NaN, we should use isNaN function

Comment: Is `input[readonly]` a wrong selector [here](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/blob/master/acadgild/assignments/session7/assignment3/file.html)?

Comment: @overexchange - No it is fine. However, with the code we are writing, once setting the attribute we are never removing it. Hence, the style will be applicable whenever readonly attribute has been added to element

Comment: On removing the attribute the code does not work. Please test it.

Comment: @overexchange - here is a working version - http://plnkr.co/edit/nlmzAdgFOubS0SBcUoFV?p=preview

Comment: @overexchange - There were 3 issues. 1. There was no form element. 2. Css selector should be readonly and not read-only. 3. There is no need for window.onload in fiddle. Please see the updated code at - https://jsfiddle.net/puxgf053/1/

Comment: @overexchange - please elaborate

Comment: @overexchange - It does for me.